# shorten case_when syntax when applying between command over multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Lets say we're using `mtcars` dataset and want to create a variable based on another within a certain interval, I can use `between` command and `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(
    between(cyl, 0, 170)~ cyl,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_)
  )
```

However is there a way to shorten this if we are looking over many variables (say 30+) at once within the same intervals. For example, take just 5 variables here:

```
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(
      between(cyl, 0, 170) & 
      between(disp, 0, 170) &
      between(hp, 0, 170) &
      between(drat, 0, 170) &
      between(wt, 0, 170) ~ cyl,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_)   
  )
```

I thought there could be a way using `all` command and passing a vector of the variables through `%in%` but cant think of a way. Would anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to create the logical columns with `mutate_at`, then `reduce` to a single logical `vector` for passing onto `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)
test1 <- mtcars %>%
          mutate_at(vars(cyl:wt), list(new= ~ between(., 0, 170))) %>% 
          mutate(new_var = case_when(reduce(select(.,ends_with('new')), `&`) 
               ~ cyl, TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
         select(-ends_with('new'))
all.equal(test, test1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Another option is `map`

```
mtcars %>%
   select(cyl:wt) %>%
   map(~ between(.x, 0, 170)) %>%
   reduce(`&`) %>%
   bind_cols(mtcars, new_var = .) %>%
   mutate(new_var = case_when(new_var ~ cyl, TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Comment: Also consider this variation: `mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new_var = 
    select(., cyl:wt) %>%
    between(0, 170) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>%
    reduce(\`&\`),
    new_var = if_else(new_var, cyl, NA_real_))`

Answer (score 2):

More towards base R but also an option:

```
vars <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt")
our_check <- function(x) between(x, 0, 170)
our_cases <- sapply(mtcars[vars], our_check) %>% 
  rowSums() %>% 
  `==`(., length(vars))

mtcars$new_var <- ifelse(our_cases, mtcars$cyl, NA_real_)
```

Or avoid any package dependency (as Ronak suggests):

```
mtcars$new_var <- ifelse(rowSums(mtcars[vars] >= 0 & mtcars[vars] <= 170) == length(vars), mtcars$cyl, NA)
```

Comment: keep it completely in base R? `mtcars$new_var <- ifelse(rowSums(mtcars[vars] >= 0 & mtcars[vars] <= 170) == length(vars), mtcars$cyl, NA)`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be:

```
mtcars %>% 
 mutate(new_var = if_else(rowSums(select(., cyl:wt) > 170 | select(., cyl:wt) < 0 ) == 0,
                          cyl, 
                          NA_real_))

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_var
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       6
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       6
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       4
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      NA
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      NA
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      NA
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4      NA
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2       4
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2       4
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4       6
```